# Hibernate columntransformer add unnecessarily reference to table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am facing following problem. Above one field I have annotation:

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(ACTIVE_START_DATE AS timestamp), 'UTC')at time zone ACTIVE_DATE_TZ) as date")
```

But when the hibernate make query from this transformer it treats the timestamp or at time zone or as date as a column of my entity and finally I have following query (part of it): `CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(user0_ACTIVE_START_DATE as user0_timestamp), 'UTC' user0_at user0_time user0_zone.`

Is any way to tell hibernate to treat those values as the oracle variable, not the entity/table fields?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I did some ugly workaround but did not remember exactly implementation.

Answer (score 0):

@ColumnTransformer(read = "FROM_TZ(CAST(ACTIVE_START_DATE AS timestamp), 'UTC')at time zone ACTIVE_DATE_TZ as date")

Comment: You only deleted the first CAST it does not help, as the hibernate still will do reference to entity/table like user0_timpestamp.